# How to cancel node selection in nodemouseclick event

Tags: c#, winforms, events, treeview

Is there a way to cancel the selection of a new node inside a `NodeMouseClick` event? (By "cancel", I mean have the selection revert to the previously selected node.)

This was easy in WPF by handling the `e.handled` boolean variable. In Winforms there's no such thing so I really don't know how I should handle this problem.

Comment: Doing it with NodeMouseClick is difficult, you have to override WndProc() to ensure that the native control doesn't see the click.  It is trivial when you use BeforeSelect, the event designed to allow you to cancel selection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about in [`BeforeSelect Event`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treeview.beforeselect.aspx)?

```
 private void treeView1_BeforeSelect(object sender, TreeViewCancelEventArgs e)
        {
            e.Cancel = true;
        }
```